# Meteor AutoForm simpleSchema this.field function does not work

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I am getting a trouble to use SimpleSchema in Meteor.

What I've aimed is to change "min" field based on "type" field value so I wrote this code.

```
'min': {
    type: Number,
    optional: true,
    label: function() {
      if(this.field('type').value == "Year") {
        return "Minimum Year"
      }
      return "Minimum Value"
    }
  },
```

But when I debug it, it shows this is blank object.

I don't have really idea how to handle this issue.

Please help me!

Comment: `label` option doesn't have `this.field()`, try using `custom`

Comment: Then how to handle label?
I am using autoform quickfield as below. 
{{> afQuickField name="min"}}

Comment: You can create  helper and attach to label field in afQuickField

Comment: Can you please teach me by instance?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps ,

```
{{> afQuickField name="min" label=checking}}

Template.x.helpers({
  checking:function(){
    if(Autoform.getFieldValue(field,formId)=="expected") 
      return "expected label"
    else
      return ""
  } 
})
```

Comment: I think it's not reliable to apply helpers to all templates that using the schema. So what about if I use Template.RegisterHelper instead of Template.x.helpers ?